# Python. Объединение файлов с сохранением заливок ячеек

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Прошу совета. Есть несколько однотипных xlsx таблиц с разной и произвольной заливкой ячеек. Подскажите, как объединить эти таблицы в один файл, чтобы сохранились все заливки ячеек?